# Why does $(RANDOM) work differently from $(ls -la)?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

for command substitution in bash, we do this

```
hello=$(ls -la)  
echo "$hello"
```

but when i do the same for below command,it fails,it says RANDOM  not found

```
hell=$(RANDOM)
echo "$hell"
```

I can get over it ,by using arithematic expansion..

```
hell=$((RANDOM))
echo "$hell"
```

Any idea why below doesn't work...as per my understanding, RANDOM is also a command and i should have gotten number echoed

```
hell=$(RANDOM)
echo "$hell"
```

Comment: `RANDOM` directly fails on bash,but `echo $RANDOM` works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RANDOM` isn't a command, it's a variable. Just [one set by the shell and a bit of a special one](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> RANDOM
> Each time this parameter<sup>(*)</sup> is referenced, it expands to a random integer between 0 and 32767. Assigning a value to this variable seeds the random number generator. If RANDOM is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

Something like `echo "$RANDOM"` is exactly how you'd use any variable, like the more "normal", `HOME` and `BASH_VERSION`. Of course `${RANDOM}`, with braces and not regular parentheses works too.

Being able to use it in an arithmetic expansion without the `$` is also a feature of the [arithmetic context](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html), and works for any variable:

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

(e.g. `x=4; echo "$((x*x))"` prints `16`)

<sub>(* You can ignore the variable vs. parameter distinction here.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the clarification ,still learning bash. It's very complicated compared to modern languages

Comment: @TheGameiswar, being a rather direct descendant of a 40+ year old shell comes with some, ah, quirks. Plus the terseness, one really has to be careful with the special characters, `$(foo)`, `$((foo))` and `${foo}` are all somewhat different.